# Insert one table and use their PK durning inserting second table as FK - SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have csv file with address and person data in each row.
I want to transform this data:
1-Insert address part od row into Address table of db
2-Use PK of added address row durning added person part of data to Person table which have FK to address column
3-Person table have FK to exist in database data, how to select PK of exist data durning ssis tranformation?

I have little experience with SSIS and I want to know how to achive that transformation?

It is possible to save address PK in some temp ?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are inserting into a MS SQL Server database, and if so is the PK of Address an IDENTITY column?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I have no amazing story to tell you with SSIS and capturing identity values. The Destination components are just that, destinations. The only output from them is an error path.

You can still use the power of SSIS for parsing flat files, logging, configuration, etc. The two typical patterns I've seen with what you are asking for is to A) load the flat file into a staging table and then use pure TSQL to load the tables and capture the output virtual table. B) assumes you have a unique identifier in your source data which you can then use to create a unique mapping between source data and destination (lookup + cache transformation is the key). Odds are long on B though, I've been able to use that once to every 10/20 imports I do with the former pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the destination tables, I'd recommend the following:

1. Add a sequence number column to the data source. [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908460) may help.
2. Add a column to both target tables to accept the sequence number data type (whatever you may use).
3. Use separate data flows for Address and Person making sure that Address goes first. Map the seq. number columns appropriately.
4. In the Person data flow, use the Lookup component against the Address table utilizing the Seq number as the key to lookup against. Fill in the Foreign Key value appropriately.

Comment: You can avoid a second data flow (and Lookup) by using a Multicast after assigning the sequence number. One output goes to a destination for Address and the second output goes to a destination for Person.

Answer (score 0):

Just do that in two different data flows.

On the first you read and insert the Addreess part and on the second  you read the Person part and join it with the Address table just created (you can use a lookup component to get the ID based on the name)

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you can add a field that will not display on the application for the file unique_id in the table and then use that in a join to the data to populate the child tables.  But sometimes you can't mess with the structure of a database especially if it is a COTS product.

We have a sneaky trick for that. First load the data to a staging table (adding an identity if the file has no unique identifier on it's own) and an empty field for the parent_id.

Next put the unique identifier into some other required field instead of its normal value (We use last_name but if you have one taht is the same datatype as the uniqueid that's better). Then you can join on the required field and the uniqueid from the staging table to update it to get the real parentid. Then update the field where you stored the temporary id with its real value (becasue now you can use teh real parent_id). Now you have the real parent_id in a table, the data flows for the child tables can join to that. This creates more work for the database, so only use it if you can't change the structure.

Alternatively you can do all the inserting from a staging table using a stored proc and the execute SQL task rather than in a dataflow.