# Get Primary Key from insert

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm attempting to use SSIS to do a data migration from an old system to a new system. I have the tables `TableA`, `TableB` and `OldTable`. The tables are as follows:

`TableA`

- ID
- BusinessTypeEnum
- Other

`TableB`

- ID
- TableB_ID (FK)
- PermitNumber

`OldTable`

- ID
- BusinessType
- PermitNumber

As you can see, `TableA` and `TableB` (which are in the new system) are really `OldTable` separated out into two tables.

My problem is that in order to insert a record in `TableB` I need to know that `PrimaryKey` that was assigned at the time the corresponding records was inserted in `TableA`.

I had originally planned on doing a `LookUp` when attempting to insert records into table `TableB` however, there isn't any data stored in `TableA` that would allow me to return.

Any ideas?

Comment: One way would be to create a stored procedure to do this row by row and call it in your package as a SQL command destination. Each row inserts (or not) Table_A, collects the ID with the scope_identity() function, then inserts into Table_B using the FK. The other way is to use a staging table. Insert Table_A in one batch, generating the FK's, then update those back on the staging table and insert the staging table (with the derived FK's)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, you don;t need to do row by row processing in teh stored proc is you get the info out using the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: Related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9709809/181965)

Comment: Perhaps you could add a more detailed answer HLGEM. I'm sure that would work but I think you'd need to explain how to transform the full rowset into FK's that are usable

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a single data flow: *source -> split -> two destinations (`TableA`, `TableB`)*.

What if you divided the process into two data flows?

- The first simply pulls from `OldTable` and loads into `TableA`.
- The second--loading into `TableB`--again pulls from `OldTable` but also gets the relevant identity value from `TableA` by doing a `Merge Join` to, or a `Lookup` from, that table.

(Note: the second flow needs to be set to run only after the first completes via a precedence constraint as it relies on `OldTable`'s data being inserted into `TableA` before its run.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) in our insert statement to return the value of the identity column.

```
INSERT TableA (BusinessTypeEnum, Other)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES ('abc', 'def')
```

in addition to inserting a record, the above will act like a select.

I should mention that there is an INTO clause in the OUTPUT clause that can be used with a batch insert. The above example is for a single record insert.